# What's a good metaphor for code?

Tags: icons

I'm playing with a user interface, with options like "preview", "view code", "drag and drop" and the such, and am creating icons for them.

What would have the meaning of "code"? I was thinking something like "<..>" or "<...>" or "`<code>`" in a Courier New font, but I would like to see if someone has anything better or suggestions.

Comment: I realize this question is too localized, please close it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of selecting a good icon is simple: if there's no obvious or standard image associated with the action, just label the control with the word.

In your case, `<code>` in a monospace font *might* be the best solution unless this style stands out from the surrounding controls.

Finally, you should've [read the FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq): asking icon suggestions isn't the best use of everyone's time.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the FAQ before asking, but thanks for taking the time to answer despite my not following the guidelines!